# Density vs distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

I have a following question:
Let say that we have given some density function $f$ of some random variable $X$. Can we say that we already know distribution of $X$ or we have to compute distribution function $F(t)=P(X\le t)$? I have always known that we have to compute $F$, but look, let say we have density function $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$. We know that $X$ is exponentially distributed...

Comment: There are cases where there is  a simple expression for $f$ but you cannot write down $F$ in terms if elmentary functions, as in the case of normal distribution. So you can say you know the CDF only when you are able to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x)dx$.

Comment: If it's you, then it depends on whether or not you can do everything you need with just the pdf. Obviously, if you end up needing to evaluate cdf, then you have to do something about it. If it's the person who's evaluating some work of yours, then you'd better ask him what he wants.

Comment: So, when somebody asks me about distribution of random variable, can I write him only density function?